# taking out sets of every 3 element from table (java)

Tags: java

I would like to take sets of every 3 elements from table, and then use them for some calculations. Let's say that my table is really big, e.g. 1000+ elements. 
Tab elements are like like {x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...}.
I want to take the first three elements, do some calculations with them, take the next three elements, etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double z=0;

    for (int i =0; i<tab.length; i++) 
        x= (double)tab[i];
            for (int j =0; j<tab.length; j+=2) 
            y= (double)tab[j];  
                for (int k =0; k<tab.length; k+=3) 
                z= (double)tab[k];      

                deathstar(x, y, z);
```

This is using only last 3 elements from `tab` and deathstar is printing calculation made only on last 3 elements. I was playing around with `{}`, but it didn't give me results that i wanted. Anyone have any solid idea how to take out every 3 elements from my table ? `tab`  is defined outside of this code and is of type `int[]`.

Thank You in advance for any thoughts about given issue.

Comment: No wonder the Rebellion found a flaw...

Comment: tab is int [], This code does take elements from it and makes calculation, but it skips through all elements, and is using only last 3.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: Thank You all, now it works as intended.

Comment: If some of the answers were helpful, you [may want to give them an upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and/or accept the answer that solved your problem best.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the increment part of the loop and increment after each element is gotten.

```
for (int i =0; i<tab.length;) {
    X=(double)tab[i++];
    Y=(double)tab[i++];
    Z=(double)tab[i++];
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i =3; i<tab.length; i+=3){ 
     tab[i-1]
     tab[i-2]
     tab[i-3]
     }
```

maybe this approach will help you

Answer (score 0):

This will grab three consecutive elements at a time and then do the calculation. Also checkS to make sure it won't go out of bounds.

```
double x=0;
double y=0;
double z=0;
int j = 1;
int k = 2;
for (int i =0; i<tab.length; i++) 
  { 
   if(i + j < tab.length && i + k < tab.length){ 
    x= (double)tab[i];
    y= (double)tab[i + j];  
    z= (double)tab[i + k];      
    deathstar(x, y, z);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `{` after the last `for`, and so `deathstar` is only called after all loops finished. Better use `{` for every for-loop. You could find this easily using a Debugger.

Next, you will ask what's wrong with the logic and why yoou don't get the expected result, because now you would get `deathstar(x1,y1,z1), deathstar(x1,y1,z2),...`. Try the following (note: I'm assuming the length of `tab` is indeed a multiple of 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i += 3) {
  x = tab[i];
  y = tab[i+1];
  z = tab[i+2];
  deathstar(x, y, z);
}
```

This way your code looks much cleaner.